# Bandpass filter for audio wav file

Tags: audio, python, audio-processing

How do I apply a bandpass filter on an audio file which is in wav format?
And write back the filtered data in a new wav file for further analysis.

Comment: What have you tried? What tutorials/books/online resources have you read? This is a pretty basic task that is well documented.

Comment: So I've looked/tried/read ThinkDSP by [AllenDowney](https://github.com/AllenDowney/ThinkDSP/blob/master/book/thinkdsp.tex) but it relies heavily on the thinkDSP library. I want a more robust solution. I have a matlab code that works wonderfully. I want to implement it in python as well.

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24920346/filtering-a-wav-file-using-python), they discussed similar topic to yours

Comment: Using sox: https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/45868/bandpass-filter-using-sox

Answer (score 1):

Consider looking at [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12233959) which provides the full code for creating a Butterworth bandpass filter. In the sample code the answerer provides, the filter is applied to a manually constructed simplistic signal `x`. If you substitute this signal with your own NumPy array, it should achieve the intended effect.

WAV files can be quickly made into NumPy arrays, consider using the `librosa` module. [librosa.core.load](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/generated/librosa.core.load.html) will be what you use. To write out the filtered signal, simply use [librosa.output.write_wav](https://librosa.github.io/librosa/ioformats.html#write-out-audio-files).

Comment: https://pysoundfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ is nice

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.io import wavfile

WAV_FILE_NAME = 'my_audio.wav'
lowcut = 1200.0
highcut = 1300.0
FRAME_RATE = 16000

def butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    low = lowcut / nyq
    high = highcut / nyq
    b, a = butter(order, [low, high], btype='band')
    return b, a

def butter_bandpass_filter(data, lowcut, highcut, fs, order=5):
    b, a = butter_bandpass(lowcut, highcut, fs, order=order)
    y = lfilter(b, a, data)
    return y

def bandpass_filter(buffer):
    return butter_bandpass_filter(buffer, lowcut, highcut, FRAME_RATE, order=6)

samplerate, data = wavfile.read(os.path.join(record_path, WAV_FILE_NAME))
assert samplerate == FRAME_RATE
filtered = np.apply_along_axis(bandpass_filter, 0, data).astype('int16')
wavfile.write(os.path.join(record_path, f'filtered_{WAV_FILE_NAME}'), samplerate, filtered)
```